# Android Studio show function references?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide, android-studio

In Visual Studio 2012, I know you can enable the ability to display the references to a function above the definition. See This link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/11/17/improvements-to-find-all-references-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx.

Is that possible in Android Studio?

Comment: Right click on the method and click find usages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android Studio Shortcut: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>

Eclipse Shortcut: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

Eclipse `Find references` equivalent in Android Studio is `Find usages` on right click.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac

<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> will find next occurrence in same file

<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> will find previous occurrence

On Mac: To find occurrences across the workspace

<kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>option / alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>